# Set Android Device as a HTTP Proxy Server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, http-proxy, android-vpn-service

Are there any way to set an Android Phone become a http-proxy server which the other devices can use the server to browser the internet? I know may use some sockets code ,but are there any open source I can use? Or are there any website talk about that.

Comment: `are there any open source I can use` you should not ask for a library here. There are some, but you have to use search to find them.

Comment: If your mobile provider allows the proxy phone to act as a mobile hotspot, you can simply turn on that feature in Android's settings on the proxy phone and then connect other phones to the hotspot via WiFi to gain Internet service. No code needed, everything is handled at the OS layer for you. I use this feature to give Internet access to my kids' non-cellular tablets when we are away from home